# How to skip analysis of folders in VSCode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, roslyn-code-analysis

how do you skip analysis of certain folders inside of my Unity-project with VSCode?

I already created a file called ".editorconfig" inside of my root folder.

The file consists of the following content:

```
root = true

[Assets/_thirdparty/**/**/*.cs]
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none

[Assets/Plugins/Debugging Essentials/**/*.cs]
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none

[Assets/UI/XmlLayout/*.cs]
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

The strange thing is that it doesn't work because the Roslyn analyzer still analyzes the appropriate .cs-files in my project and throws out some errors and warnings.

So how can I prevent Roslyn from analyzing my folders which I mentioned above? Thanks in advance.